# Obj-C - Google Places return both street number and name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

I've created a textfield that uses Google Places API to auto-complete the user's address as they type it in. That said, Google Places searches the street number as the user types, but as soon as they get to inputting their street name, the results stop narrowing down.

**For example**: if I type in *1022 Homer Street*, Google Places returns the top 5 results containing 1022, but disregards the Homer Street portion.

See the below string I'm currently using to populate the result.

```
 NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%@&types=street_address&location=49.266912500000004,-123.09886619999999&radius=25000&strictbounds&key=AIzaSyAm7buitimhMgE1dKV2j4_7doULluiiDzU", strSearch];
```

Comment: i have copy-paste your url and checked. it seems like working. google return all response with homer street portion.

Comment: That is bizarre... will dig a bit deeper into my code then - thanks @NiravKotecha!